# i want my div slideup when clicked anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

```
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

I want to slide up my div when click outside of it, anywhere on page.

Comment: Please include your HTML code, perhaps a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rvra3/ 

my code is like this. but it seems not working on jsfiddle

Comment: That's because you didn't load jQuery on your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').not('.slidingDiv').click(function(){
    $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
});
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    if($('.slidingDiv:hover').length===0) $('.slidingDiv').slideUp();
});
```